# DataTable to a List<DataTable>

Tags: c#, list, datatable, datarow, datacolumn

**I created a DataTable List:**

```
List<DataTable> dataTableList = new List<DataTable>();
```

**I created a temp DataTable with Columns:**

```
DataTable tmp = new DataTable();
tmp.Columns.Add("SenderCostCenter" , typeof(String));
tmp.Columns.Add("ActivityType" , typeof(String));
tmp.Columns.Add("Quantity" , typeof(String));
tmp.Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(String));
tmp.Columns.Add("Costcnter" , typeof(String));
tmp.Columns.Add("InternalOrder" , typeof(String));
tmp.Columns.Add("WBSElement" , typeof(String));
tmp.Columns.Add("SalesOrder", typeof(String));
tmp.Columns.Add("SalesOrderItem" , typeof(String));
tmp.Columns.Add("Text" , typeof(String));
```

**Then I imported some data and filled the `tmp` DataTable with it**
I recreate this `tmp` DataTable 13 times in a loop.
This loop is inside another loop and inside the outer loop, after the inner loop I want to fill the DataTable List with my tmp Data Tables
**This is my code:**

```
dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("SenderCostSender" , typeof(String));
dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("ActivityType", typeof(String));
dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(String));
dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(String));
dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("Costcenter", typeof(String));
dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("InternalOrder", typeof(String));
dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("WBSElement", typeof(String));
dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("SalesOrder", typeof(String));
dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("SalesOrderItem", typeof(String));
dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("Text" , typeof(String));
dataTableList[fs1] = tmp;
```

`fs1` is the outer loop variable to iterate through the DataTableList.

The data import works fine but when the program reaches: `dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("SenderCostSender" , typeof(string));` I get a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` Error.

I would appreciate any kind of help, thanks.

Here is the complete Method: (the `List<dataTable>` is global)

```
 using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                //Folder-Browser-Dialog öffnen
                DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
                {
                    //Menge an Excel-Daten rausfinden
                    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath , "*.xlsx");
                    for (int fs1=0;fs1<=files.Length;fs1++)
                    {
                        //Excel Import
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(files[fs1]);
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet _Worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = _Worksheet.UsedRange;

                        //Neues DataTable 
                        DataTable tmp = new DataTable();
                        tmp.Columns.Add("SenderCostCenter" , typeof(String));
                        tmp.Columns.Add("ActivityType" , typeof(String));
                        tmp.Columns.Add("Quantity" , typeof(String));
                        tmp.Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(String));
                        tmp.Columns.Add("Costcnter" , typeof(String));
                        tmp.Columns.Add("InternalOrder" , typeof(String));
                        tmp.Columns.Add("WBSElement" , typeof(String));
                        tmp.Columns.Add("SalesOrder", typeof(String));
                        tmp.Columns.Add("SalesOrderItem" , typeof(String));
                        tmp.Columns.Add("Text" , typeof(String));

                        //DataTable füllen
                        for (int fs2 = 24; fs2 <= range.Rows.Count; fs2++)
                        {
                            //DataRow erstellen & füllen
                            DataRow dataRow = tmp.NewRow();
                            dataRow[0] = Convert.ToString(range.Cells[fs2, 2].Value2);
                            dataRow[1] = Convert.ToString(range.Cells[fs2, 3].Value2);
                            dataRow[2] = Convert.ToString(range.Cells[fs2, 4].Value2);
                            dataRow[3] = Convert.ToString(range.Cells[fs2, 5].Value2);
                            dataRow[4] = Convert.ToString(range.Cells[fs2, 6].Value2);
                            dataRow[5] = Convert.ToString(range.Cells[fs2, 7].Value2);
                            dataRow[6] = Convert.ToString(range.Cells[fs2, 8].Value2);
                            dataRow[7] = Convert.ToString(range.Cells[fs2, 9].Value2);
                            dataRow[8] = Convert.ToString(range.Cells[fs2, 10].Value2);
                            dataRow[9] = Convert.ToString(range.Cells[fs2, 11].Value2);
                            tmp.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                        }

                        //tmp DataTable in die Globale DataTable-List kopieren
                        dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("SenderCostSender" , typeof(String));
                        dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("ActivityType", typeof(String));
                        dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(String));
                        dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(String));
                        dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("Costcenter", typeof(String));
                        dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("InternalOrder", typeof(String));
                        dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("WBSElement", typeof(String));
                        dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("SalesOrder", typeof(String));
                        dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("SalesOrderItem", typeof(String));
                        dataTableList[fs1].Columns.Add("Text" , typeof(String));
                        dataTableList[fs1] = tmp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I removed the forced tag from your question's title. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) why.

Comment: Your code as posted contains logical errors. Maybe they came from shortening it for the example here. Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Which means that `fs1` has an invalid value. Where does `fs1` come from? A loop variable? Hard-coded number?

Comment: Additionally: Consider using a DataView and to create the temporary table from that

Comment: You are trying to add columns to whatever `DataTable` is stored at index `fs1` (is there any or is it null?) and then overwrite that with the table in `tmp`.

Comment: why dont you use `DataSet` instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataTable   d = new DataTable();         
List<DataTable> l = new List<DataTable>();
l.Add(d);
```